# React: Render canvas at certain framerate

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

Pretty new to React, trying to understand its basics. 
I want to render video content to a canvas while it is playing. My solution will cause an overflow. How can I manage recursive calls like this?

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';


class VideoPlayer extends React.Component {

    componentDidMount() {
        this.context = this.refs.canvas.getContext('2d');
    }

    play() {
        if (this.refs.video.paused) {
            this.refs.video.play();
            this.updateCanvas();
        } else {
            this.refs.video.pause();
        }
    }

    updateCanvas() {
        if (this.refs.video.paused || this.refs.video.ended) {
            return;
        }

        let fps = 30;
        this.context.drawImage(this.refs.video, 0, 0, 400, 220);

        setTimeout(requestAnimationFrame(this.updateCanvas()), 1000 / fps);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <video width="400" ref="video" id="v">
                    <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>
                </video>
                <canvas ref="canvas" width="400" height="220"></canvas>
                <br/>
                <button type="button" onClick={this.play.bind(this)}>Play</button>
            </div>

        );
    }
}

export default VideoPlayer;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to make a call at regular intervals, it's better to use `setInterval` and `clearInterval` over `setTimeout`. Recursion is always a bit tricky, and dealing with delays makes the entire approach even trickier.

So the idea, then, becomes to program a `setInterval` when play is pressed (and the video is not yet playing) that will copy the current video frame into the canvas, and do that at a rate of *n* fps. The returned `interval` handler will be saved into the component's state.

When play is pressed again (and the video is running), the interval function will be cleared by invoking `clearInterval` with the `interval` value saved in the state.

In addition, to handle the case where we let the video run its course, if the `interval` handler is set in the state when we press play (and the video is not yet running), then we just call `clearInterval` with the `interval` handler present in the state (if you don't do this, you will have uncleared intervals piling up every time a video runs to its end = memory leak).

In order to get a copy of the *current* video frame, we also implement a very basic `grabFrame` method, and we make sure it is bound to the component's context.

Finally, the rate at which we grab a copy (i.e. the FPS) is passed to the component as a prop.

```
class VideoPlayer extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      interval: undefined,
      ctx: undefined
    };

    this.grabFrame = this.grabFrame.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
      ctx: this.canvas.getContext("2d")
    });
  }

  grabFrame() {
    return this.state.ctx.drawImage(this.video, 0, 0, 400, 220);
  }

  play() {
    if (this.video.paused) {
      if (this.state.interval) {
        clearInterval(this.state.interval);
      }
      this.video.play();
      this.setState({
        interval: setInterval(this.grabFrame, 1000 / this.props.fps)
      });
    } else {
      clearInterval(this.state.interval);
      this.setState({
        interval: undefined
      });
      this.video.pause();
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <video width="400" ref={video => (this.video = video)} id="v">
          <source
            src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4"
            type="video/mp4"
          />
        </video>
        <canvas
          ref={canvas => (this.canvas = canvas)}
          width="400"
          height="220"
        />
        <br />
        <button type="button" onClick={this.play.bind(this)}>
          Play
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

See [this CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/mk8596pxp) for a working example.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation